Posts Created Programmatically Require a Manual Update In Wordpress for ACF Fields
I have a wordpress website with a custom post type that has posts created programatically when a new item is created in SoundCloud. These posts have ACF fields – among them is an event_date field that is a datepicker.
All is working perfectly with the post creation. The issue is that when I display these posts on the front end of my website sorted by event_date in DESC order, they appear out of order. This only occurs initially after the post is created programatically.  If I open up the post in the WP Admin and then save them (without changing anything) then they will then appear in the correct sort order. Its like that field has to be re-initialized after the post is created programatically with a manual save. Any ideas how to resolve the issue without going into each post manually each day?
I did build a cron that ran wp_udpate_post on each post with just the post ID as an argument, but it didn’t resolve the issue.

My guess is that you are adding meta data via the ACF field name, not the field key, so event_date and not field_123456. If that's the case, they recommend inserting with the key, and only using the name for updating and fetching, see https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/#updating-via-field-key

Try this solution:

Use update_field() function for the event_date field as this function saves the value in a way that ACF and WP recognize.

Re-save the post meta with acf_update_value:
acf_update_value($event_date, $post_id, 'event_date');

Also check if the event_date format is consistent and correct throughout.



Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.
